# Installing only single package via Composer without updating other packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to install a single composer package into a project - `maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0`. Each time composer updates, it updates all packages in composer.json. How can I avoid updating packages aside from the excel library?

I have tried the following commands but they don't seem to be working:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0
composer require vendor/maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0
composer update maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0
composer update vendor/maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0
```

I've also tried using the --lock attribute but that's also not working.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Should be able to edit composer.json to set the package version you want (~2.1.0), and then just `composer update maatwebsite/excel`

Comment: @Laki98 I am sure the composer might be updating only the dependencies of the `maatwebsite/excel` package and not everything in your vendor folder. Can you paste the output?

Comment: @prateekkathal it has downloaded and updated all dependencies again, just like did before. I'll copy the output right down in the answer.

Comment: @Laki98 You can take a sreenshot and give me that link also...

Comment: It's updating the dependencies required by the package you're updating.  Nothing wrong here.  You can exclude the dev dependencies by doing `composer update --no-dev maatwebsite/excel`.

Comment: @drew010 i ran "composer update --no-dev maatwebsite/excel" and it actually downloaded most of the packages (not only excel's one), but seemed to work after that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

To install a composer package with a specific version the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) suggest the use of a colon.

`composer require maatwebsite/excel:~2.1.0 --no-update`

Also, the composer cli tool `composer help require` help reads:

> Required package name optionally including a version constraint, e.g.
>   foo/bar or foo/bar:1.0.0 or foo/bar=1.0.0 or "foo/bar 1.0.0"

So to use a space separated version number, you needed the quotation marks surrounding the package/version combination.  That is:

`composer require "maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0" --no-update`

should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but again, in both ways ALL dependencies from composer.json are being updated.

Answer (score 1):

To skip updates on **any other package**, simply add `--no-update` to your call. This instructs Composer to only require that new package and not update anything else.

The resulting call could then look like the following:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0 --no-update
```